# Why has $evB$ been equated to $mv^2/R$ here?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, energy-conservation, binding-energy

When $24.8 keV$ x-rays strike a material, the photoelectrons emitted from K shell are observed to move in a circle of radius $23mm$ in a magnetic field of 2 × $10^{-2}$. The binding energy of K shell electrons

Now the solution is something like this
[image]

My doubt is why have they equated $evB$ to $Mv^2/R$??

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format equations rather than images. Images are not accessible to everyone.

Comment: @BioPhysicist Ok sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The electrons are undergoing uniform circular motion due to the magnetic force. Therefore, the centripetal force component is equal to the magnetic force. I'll leave the calculation (if you can call it that?) to you.

Answer (score 1):

$F=BqV$ is the force experienced by a moving charge in a magnetic field.so, as charge  moves in circular path we equate this to the required centripetal force(=$\frac{mv^2}{r}$)now you can proceed with the solution